# ReactJS In-Line Function Running Before Component Mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a div that should be hidden unless a certain `<option>` is selected in a `<select>` element

```
<div id='mailingAddrElms' className='col-md-5 col-sm-6' style={{display: this.showOrHideStateProvince()}}>

showOrHideStateProvince() {
    console.log('showing or hiding state/province options!');
    let mailingAddrElms = document.getElementById('mailingAddrElms');
    let prevAddrElms = document.getElementById('prevAddrElms');
    console.log(mailingAddrElms);
    console.log(prevAddrElms);
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MOUNTED');
}
```

The showOrHideStateProvince() method is being ran before the component mounts as can be seen from this console output.

> showing or hiding state/province options!
>
> AddressForm.js:181 null
>
> AddressForm.js:182 null
>
> AddressForm.js:186 MOUNTED

It is very important that I wait for the component to mount before trying to retrieve elements by ID because then my magic controls won't be magical...

Any help is much appreciated, this is my first professional proj using React and I had no time to get ramped up..

I hope I shared enough snippets to paint the picture of my issue, but I really cannot be showing much more...

Comment: it would be better if you can show the whole component just obscure the ones you don't want to be seen. i'm guessing that showhide function will return a display object dependent on whatever results it'll process. Why not create a state , `showProvinceOptions` that will hide these options, and just have a method that will toggle that state on and off?

Comment: you could do simple `{ showProvinceOptions && <OptionsContainer >...<> }` to hide these options instead of relying on display.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called *after* render. You need to be able to render meaningfully before pretty much anything else happens.

Comment: @FranreySaycon This actually ended up working for me. I already had a separate method recording state that would tell the method shown in my question to hide or show the elements. A simple ternary operator on the style attribute fixed everything. I don't even need the method showOrHideStateProvince(). Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling the `showOrHideStateProvince` method within `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Yes, but then it will just run twice. It runs once from the in-line invocation on the div element and then again once componentDidMount() runs. This doesn't solve my issue that well because there will be a FOUSC a split second before the component mounts.

Comment: So instead you can have showOrHideStateProvince set a flag in your state and use that flag for display

ie:
 ```showOrHideStateProvince() {
this.setState({
  display: true
})
    console.log('showing or hiding state/province options!');
    let mailingAddrElms = document.getElementById('mailingAddrElms');
    let prevAddrElms = document.getElementById('prevAddrElms');
    console.log(mailingAddrElms);
    console.log(prevAddrElms);
}```

Answer (score 0):

Per @FranreySaycon comment, replacing the in-line function call on the div element with a ternary operator based on component state solves this issue painlessly. I just have a separate function now to record state then the ternary operator returns styles to the div.